# R: index() can not return desired class

Tags: r, xts

I have the following **xts** object with indexClass "Date". `index(data)` gives me "POSIXct" object. I thought `index(Data)` will return an "Date" object.

How can I get "Date" object from `index()`?

```
str(data)
An ‘xts’ object from 2007-01-15 to 2012-04-27 containing:
  Data: num [1:1282, 1:5] 1881 2003 2064 2026 2098 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "open" "high" "low" "close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: GMT
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ tclass: chr "Date"
 $ tzone : chr "GMT"

 indexClass(data)
 "Date"

str(index(data))
Class 'POSIXct'  atomic [1:1282] 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 1.17e+09 ...
  ..- attr(*, "tzone")= chr "GMT"
  ..- attr(*, "tclass")= chr "Date"
```

Comment: Following on from my answer below, I have a question: How did you create your data?! I cannot work out how to add a timezone to an xts index when it is a Date. (I'm wondering if indexDate(x) gives you a timezone-less Date object, but as I cannot reproduce your problem, I cannot test this.)

Comment: I guess the TZ variable is now strored in the tzone attribute when we create xts objects. If we do not need tzone attribute, how do we remove it?

Comment: I edited my answer to show that explicitly setting tzone does not make any difference. Can you edit your question to show how you create `data` that has the problem, please. Keep it minimal but it should be complete enough that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have tried your example. When I create xts objects, tzone will be added automatically. Do you update xts package? I guess new version xts will add tzone.

Comment: I'm running xts 0.8.6, ubuntu 10.04. Yet again: please show *actual code* for how you create your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: Dates don't have timezones. So it (I presume) has to wrap your Date in a POSIXct to preserve the timezone information.

Here is an example without timezones, where it shows the behaviour you expect:

```
x=xts(1:10, seq.Date(as.Date('2012-01-01'),by=1,length.out=10))
indexClass(x)
# [1] "Date"
index(x)
# "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-08" "2012-01-09" "2012-01-10"
str(index(x))
# Date[1:10], format: "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-08" "2012-01-09" "2012-01-10"
```

UPDATE: Adding the tzone attribute to the xts object does not change anything:

```
x=xts(1:10, seq.Date(as.Date('2012-01-01'),by=1,length.out=10), tzone="GMT")
str(index(x))
# Date[1:10], format: "2012-01-01" "2012-01-02" "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" "2012-01-07" "2012-01-08" "2012-01-09" "2012-01-10"
```

This is despite str(x) giving the same output as you:

```
An ‘xts’ object from 2012-01-01 to 2012-01-10 containing:
  Data: int [1:10, 1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: GMT
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ tclass: chr "Date"
 $ tzone : chr "GMT"
```